# Create a shell script to open a terminal and execute commands from that terminal

Tags: shell, sh

I have an file named seloger-cli located in  /usr/lib/

```
 /usr/lib/seloger-cli
```

While executing seloger-cli it will opens a terminal like below

```
root@testuser:/usr/lib# ./seloger-cli
<<<<< six is initialized in Multi-App Mode >>>>>>>>
Port..6--1225901584

**************************************************************************
** SELOGER APP - COMMAND LINE INTERFACE (CLI) **
**************************************************************************

[SELOGERCLI] seloger-cli>
```

From the seloger-cli command line interface I need to execute commands and the output of that command I have to write to a text file

So I have to create an sh file to run

1)seloger-cli interface

2)Execute commands from seloger-cli interface and write the output of the commands that executed from the seloger-cli  interface to a file

How it can be possbile?

Comment: May be something like this: `./seloger-cli 2>&1 | tee /tmp/output.txt`. It have to save terminal output and stderr in file.

Comment: The commands you have to type in... are they fixed and always the same? Or can you know what they are going to be before you run your command?

Comment: @Psi : From your example, it looks like there is no new terminal "opened", but you just run a new command line handler (your seloger-cli) in your current terminal. Please clarify this.

Comment: Opening the terminal of seloger by executing seloger-cli command. In the above question I have mentioned that [SELOGERCLI] seloger-cli> is the terminal opened.. Here I can execute commands

Comment: Perhaps `script -q -c './seloger-cli' output-log` cf. `man script`.